# JQUERY-DATATABLES WITH VUEJS

Tags: laravel, vue.js, datatables

I am using jquery-datatables with vuejs. Everything seems to work well but when I try to fetch more than 500 records, it gets all the records displayed with filters not working and the text "No data available in table" being shown at the top of the table followed by all records displayed.Any help will be appreciated.[image]

Here is the code:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h4 class="card-title">Products</h4>

                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <table class="table table-striped walla">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>#</th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Category</th>
                                    <th>Price</th>
                                    <th>Quantity</th>
                                    <th>Actions</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                <tr v-for="product in tableData" :key="product.id">
                                    <td>{{product.id}}</td>
                                    <td>{{product.name}}</td>
                                    <td>{{product.category}}</td>
                                    <td>{{product.price | currency}}</td>
                                    <td>{{product.quantity}}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" @click="editMode(product)"><i
                                            class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
                                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" @click="deleteProduct(product.id)"><i
                                            class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                tableData: [],
                add_product: false,
                editing: false
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.initDatatable();
            this.getProducts();

        },

        methods: {
            getProducts() {
                axios.get('products')
                    .then(res => this.tableData = res.data)
                    .catch(error => Exception.handle(error))
            },


            deleteProduct(id) {
                axios.delete(`products/${id}`)
                    .then(res => {
                        for (let i = 0; i < this.tableData.length; i++) {
                            if (this.tableData[i].id == res.data) {
                                this.tableData.splice(i, 1);
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(error => console.log(error.response))
            },
            initDatatable() {
                $('.walla').DataTable({
                    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                    "lengthMenu": [
                        [10, 25, 50, -1],
                        [10, 25, 50, "All"]
                    ],
                    order: [[0, 'asc'], [3, 'desc']],
                    responsive: true,
                    destroy: true,
                    retrieve: true,
                    autoFill: true,
                    colReorder: true,

                });
            },

            editMode(product) {
                this.$store.dispatch('updateProduct', product)
                    .then(() => {
                        this.editing = true;
                        this.add_product = true;
                    })
            }
        },

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
This solution worked for me.Even for 10,000 records.It works perfectly.
```

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h4 class="card-title">Products</h4>

                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <table class="table table-striped walla">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>#</th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Category</th>
                                    <th>Price</th>
                                    <th>Quantity</th>
                                    <th>Actions</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                <tr v-for="product in tableData" :key="product.id">
                                    <td>{{product.id}}</td>
                                    <td>{{product.name}}</td>
                                    <td>{{product.category}}</td>
                                    <td>{{product.price | currency}}</td>
                                    <td>{{product.quantity}}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" @click="editMode(product)"><i
                                            class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
                                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" @click="deleteProduct(product.id)"><i
                                            class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                tableData: [],
                add_product: false,
                editing: false
            }
        },
        created() {
          this.getProducts();
        },


        methods: {
            getProducts() {
                axios.get('products')
                    .then(res => {
                      this.tableData = res.data
                      this.initDatatable();
                    )
                    .catch(error => Exception.handle(error))
            },


            deleteProduct(id) {
                axios.delete(`products/${id}`)
                    .then(res => {
                        for (let i = 0; i < this.tableData.length; i++) {
                            if (this.tableData[i].id == res.data) {
                                this.tableData.splice(i, 1);
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(error => console.log(error.response))
            },
            initDatatable() {
                setTimeout(() => {
                $('.walla').DataTable({
                    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                    "lengthMenu": [
                        [10, 25, 50, -1],
                        [10, 25, 50, "All"]
                    ],
                    order: [[0, 'asc'], [3, 'desc']],
                    responsive: true,
                    destroy: true,
                    retrieve: true,
                    autoFill: true,
                    colReorder: true,

                });
               }, 300)
            },

            editMode(product) {
                this.$store.dispatch('updateProduct', product)
                    .then(() => {
                        this.editing = true;
                        this.add_product = true;
                    })
            }
        },

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<template>
 <div>
     <table id="datatables" >
        <thead>
     <tr>
     <th><b>Name</b></th>
     ....
     </tr>
     </thead>
    <tr v-for="item in posts" :key="item.id">
    ...
    </tr>
     </table>

 </div>
 </template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            posts:{},
        }
    },
    methods: {
        mydatatables(){
            $( function () {
                $('#datatables').DataTable({
                    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                    "lengthMenu": [
                        [10, 25, 50, -1],
                        [10, 25, 50, "All"]
                    ],
                    order: [[ 0, 'asc' ], [ 3, 'desc' ]],
                    responsive: true,
                    destroy: true,
                    retrieve:true,
                    autoFill: true,
                    colReorder: true,

                });
            });
        },
    },
    created() {
      axios.get("/api/posts").then(response => {
                this.posts= response.data.data;
                this.mydatatables();
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.It works with at most 500  records but it does not work with  1000 records

Comment: Anyone who can help on this please?

Comment: try this code **getProducts() {
                axios.get('products').then(res => {this.tableData = res.data.data;this.initDatatable(); }))**

Comment: Thank you for the response but the output is still the same.

Comment: try add **<table id="walla" class="table table-striped"> </table>**

Comment: I am still getting the same issue. no difference